# SharePoint 2013 app uninstalling behaviour

Tags: sharepoint-addin, event-receivers

I have been seeing change of behavior on O365 when app is uninstalled. Not sure if anybody experienced the same. Let me explain,

App Uninstall behavior before:

*When app is uninstalled, SharePoint deletes it permanently and triggers 'appuninstalling' event receiver immediately*

App Uninstall behavior now:

*When app is uninstalled, it goes to Recycle bin. If you remove it from Recycle bin (/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx), uninstalling event does not trigger. It triggers only when you completely remove it from Admin Recycle Bin (_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2). So, in order to trigger event you have to completely remove app from recycle bin.*

Has anyone experienced the same?

Comment: Yes we are experiencing exactly the same problem.
It gives us problems when users uninstall and install an app again on the same web. We have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Talked to MS support regarding this and He told me that this is the expected behavior for app uninstall. His argument was that app is like any other object within SharePoint and once you delete it, it should go to recycle bin for any recovery possibility. It stays there for 90 days.

I also discussed about change of behavior for Uninstalling event receiver. He agreed with me that it should trigger immediately instead of when removed from admin recycle bin because it is meant to be used for any cleanup job for the app. My gut feeling is that they will change this again because it is not making sense at all. Let’s wait for it.

Comment: For me that make a sense, just like if you remove list item and it goes to the recycle bin but you cannot create with same name/id untill it gone from recycle bin...in 2013 they treat app instance as an object.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, you explain our big problem :)